# How to use Serilog with ConfigurationBuilder in .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'm having trouble starting a worker service using the serilog logger with the ConfigurationBuilder to pull json settings from the appsettings.json. When the service is started it fails for "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start...", but works as a console app. If I remove the ConfigurationBuilder code and use the old way to initialize the logger it works great to start the service and run as a console app. Can anyone see a problem with my code below that I grabbed from the serilog gitHub for the ConfigurationBuilder method to load from appsettings.json. Maybe it's a .Net 5 problem or something.

This code below fails to start as a service, but works as a console app.

```
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();

                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                            .CreateLogger();


                try
                {
                    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Fatal("Error starting service - " + ex.ToString());
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Log.CloseAndFlush();
                }
            }

            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    }).UseSerilog();
        }
```

appsettings.json file

```
        {
          "Serilog": {
            "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
            "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "C:/repoLog.txt",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

This method works great below in console mode and the service starts fine, so it something with my ConfigurationBuilder or SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() when the service starts.

```
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.File("C:/repoLog.txt")
                    .CreateLogger();


                try
                {
                    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Fatal("Error starting service - " + ex.ToString());
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Log.CloseAndFlush();
                }
            }

            public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService()
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    }).UseSerilog();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the core service loading problem was resolved by using this ConfigurationBuilder format. The logger now works as a service and a console app.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

Comment: If this answers the question go ahead and accept it.  You can always change that later if a better answer comes along.